# discord py button and select, cant work properly

Tags: discord.py

Can anyone help me with this?

For the button, it shows: IndentationError: unexpected indent

```
@bot.command()
```

async def button(ctx):

```
await ctx.send("hello",components = [
    [Button(label="hi",style="3",custom_id="button1"), Button(label="bye",style="4",custom_id="button2")]
    ])
    interaction = await bot.wait_for("button_click", check = lambda i:i.custon_id == "button1" )
    await interaction.send(content = "BUtton Clicked", ephemeral=True)
```

For the select, it only shows urmom...

```
@bot.command()
```

async def select(ctx):
await ctx.send("Select", components= [

```
    Select( 
        placeholder = "Select Something",
             options = [
                SelectOption(label="A",value="A"),
                SelectOption(label="B",value="B")
            ])        
        ])
       
   

while True:
    try:
            select_interaction = await bot.wait_for("select_option")
            await select_interaction.send(content = f"{select_interaction.values[0]} selected", emphemral=False)
    except:
               await ctx.send("urmom")
```

Comment: Since it sends "urmom", for getting the actual error (which would make it easier for you to solve), you can simply so something like "except Exception as e: " then "print(e)".
Your indentation in the button is wrong as the lines starting "await ctx.send..." and "interaction=" should have the same indentation.

Comment: Please format the code properly using backticks (```) or indenting it 4 spaces.